# Authentication with net/http in Go isn't working

Tags: http, authentication, go

I have a problem, I have a server that logs into another server and gets some data.
The login works in NodeJS like this:

```
var data = {
    login_act: "username",
    login_pwd: "password"
};
request.post({url: 'https://example.com', form: data}, callback())`
```

and in Java like this:

```
try {
    URL mUrl = new URL("https://example.com");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

    String urlParameters  = "login_act=" + username + "&login_pwd=" + password;
    byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8");

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.write( postData );
    }
}
```

I also made a C++ implementation of the same situation:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *vManager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
QNetworkRequest req;
req.setUrl(QUrl("https://example.com"));
req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
QByteArray postData;
postData.append("login_act=" + username + "&");
postData.append("login_pwd=" + password + "");

connect(vManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(authFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
QNetworkReply *reply = vManager->post(req, postData);
reply->ignoreSslErrors();
```

But when I try to do the same in Go it refuses to log in:

```
resp, error := http.PostForm("https://example.com", url.Values{"login_act": {"username"}, "login_pwd": {"password"}})
```

The site is build in such a way that, when login fails it just returns the standard site with the login form and if login suceeds it returns a 302 statuscode.
Maybe someone can help me I'm new to the go programming language and maybe I just miss something important.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is any error returned? As a sidenote, do not name the actual error "error", but rather "err", creates less confusion. For debug measures, try POSTing to a local server, where you can see what you get, also try that with the Java and C++ implementations for comparison.

Comment: No error is returned and I compared the requests of node and go and their identical as far as i can tell.

Comment: i think capture the http (wireshark) must help finding out the problem.